# go-couchbase client Update function

Tags: go, couchbase

I am using the `Update` function of `go-couchbase`

```
//defining the function first and passing it as an argument
myfunc := func(current []byte)(updated []byte, err error) {return updated, err }
myb.Update("key123", 1, myfunc)
```

However, when I run the `Update` function of the bucket. I checked the couch database. The document with the key of "key123" was disappeared. It seems the `Update` does not update the value but delete it. What happened? Am I doing something not correct?